# Change brightness of application

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, brightness

Is it possible to programmatically change the brightness of a C++ Builder/Delphi styled application, without actually changing the style and loading it back in real time? Could not find anything like a master brightness setting. Note I do not want to change the brightness of the entire screen, just the styled elements in my application (like Adobe does).

Update: referring to VCL, not FMX.

Comment: Can you give an example? "Like adobe does" is pretty vague. Furthermore, what is a "C++ Builder/Delphi styled application"? Do you mean a FireMonkey or a VCL application?

Comment: You mean Photoshop editing an image? You want to change the brightness of an image in Delphi?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, the application itself (UI).

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful: VCL.

Comment: That's just not going to be tractable. The UI is drawn in bits and pieces. You'd need to hook into this at the DWM level. Back to the drawing board I guess.

Comment: I think you are forgetting the entire app is already styled, so only the style needs adjusting.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful Many programs do this, but here is one example http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-illustrator-cs6/adjusting-interface-brightness/.

Comment: VCL styles aren't dynamic in the way you want

Comment: I guess names of styles only makes it evident that this is not possible; how about a bright charcoal dark slate!! Also, as you can see in the video you linked, you can't achieve the desired effect by brightening every color, elements have to adapt differently. Anyway, you can choose a dark or medium or bright style.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this would work for you, but could you use a TContrastEffect? It has both a brightness and contrast property that should affect the object it's parented to and it's children when adjusted.

Comment: Thanks, should have added I use the VCL (FMX is too unstable for me).

Comment: No worries, that's understandable ;)